# tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully

Tags: python, tarfile

I have the following piece of code to open a .tgz file, but I'm getting **tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully**.

```
fp = tarfile.open('file.tgz', 'r')
print fp.list()
fp.close()
```

I can extract this archive using "tar -xvzf file.tgz." Apparently it has something to do with the way the file was created because when I compare two different .tgz files using `file`, I see a difference; file2.tgz works with this piece of code.

```
$ file file.tgz 
file.tgz: gzip compressed data, from FAT filesystem (MS-DOS, OS/2, NT)

$ file file2.tgz 
file2.tgz: gzip compressed data, was "", last modified: Tue Aug 19 11:16:10 2014, max compression
```

Any ideas why this is happening or how I can modify file.tgz so that it works with tarfile?

Note: I'm using Python 2.7.5.

Comment: Have you downloaded it ? Have you checked its checksum/hash to see if it's OK ?

Comment: How did you transfer `file.tgz` from your Windows machine to your Linux machine? Try `gzip -t file.tgz` to test for file integrity.

Comment: @CristianoAraujo I can extract using tar on my Mac so I'm assuming the file is good. I don't have access to the machine or person that generated the file to check the MD5 sum.

Comment: @Robᵩ $ gzip -t file.tgz produces no output. I guess this means that there are no problems with the file.

Comment: I don't know why it is getting that error. I would extract the files with `tar` on Mac, create a new image using `tar` on Mac, and then run my python program on the new image.

Comment: Yes, no output from `gzip -t` means OK.

Comment: I wonder if the file was compressed with an algorithm that Python doesn't support. Can you run `gzip -l --verbose file.tgz file2.tgz` to see what compression methods are used? If this is the issue, then a possible solution is `gzip -d < file.tgz | gzip -c > file_new.tgz`.

Comment: $ gzip -l --verbose file.tgz file2.tgz <br>
method  crc     date  time    compressed uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name<br>
defla c0ae42b5 Aug 25 18:54     44183154     45915653   3.7% file.tar<br>
defla 1709b914 Aug 28 10:34     82958925    495308800  83.2% file2.tar<br>
                               127142079    541224453  76.5% (totals)<br>`

Comment: @Robᵩ See the output properly formatted [here](http://shrib.com/M2fXdnbE). I could manipulate this one file to possibly make it work, but the tool I'm writing will expect .tgz files that could be equally compressed. To give some background, this file is an ESXi support file and was generated from vSphere Client on a Windows machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60183/discussion-between-rob-and-felipe).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the file was *double* compressed. I followed Rob's advice to try `gzip -l --verbose file.gz` and found the key hint that the compression ratio was negative.

```
method  crc     date  time    compressed uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
defla 8448d70e Jul  1 11:34        11176        11146  -0.3% output.gz
```

Running `tar -xvf output.gz` unarchived without issue. But Python's tarfile seemed to think it was corrupted:

```
import tarfile
tarfile.open('output.gz', 'r:gz')  # throws invalid header error
```

That's because tar appears to handle multiple levels of compression. If you uncompress it once, it should work:

```
import tarfile
import gzip
import shutil

with gzip.open('output.gz') as g:
    with open('output2.gz', 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(g, f_out)

tarfile.open('output2.gz', 'r:gz') # <tarfile.TarFile object at 0x109152690>
```

Now the compression ratio looks right:

```
gzip -l --verbose output*
method  crc     date  time    compressed uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
defla 8448d70e Jul  1 11:34        11176        11146  -0.3% output
defla 76e69d8c Jul  1 11:37        11146        44032  74.6% output2
```